# Select country first from a dropdown menu, then region and then city?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I'm using html SELECT to make 3 drop-down menus. One for a list of countries, one for regions and one for cities.

They all have different tables in the database and they are linked to each other with foreign keys.

I want to force the user to first select a country while the other two menus are locked. When he has selected a country he will be able to select a region, and then a city. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which part are you specifically having problems with?

1) Populate the countries list when the user loads the page, other 2 menus are disabled. (`SELECT * FROM Countries;`)
2) When the user selects a country, send an AJAX request to the server containing the country name. (`SELECT * FROM Regions WHERE id = country_id;`)
3) When you receive the AJAX response, populate the regions list and enable it.
4) Repeat steps 2 and 3 for the city name.

Answer (score 2):

You've got several possibilities.

1. You could write a single select that retrieves all the country-region-city combinations at one time, and use the rows to create Javascript objects representing this data at load time.  Then create a Javascript method that updates the dependent rows when a new country or region is selected.
2. You could write 3 select statements, 1 for countries, 1 for regions for a given country, and 1 for cities for a given region.  The countries select would run at page load time, and the other queries could be performed using an Ajax request when country and region are selected.

Comment: Option 2 sounds like the best.

Answer (score 2):

Try this [premade script](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex16/chainedselects/index.htm) and start accepting answers.., people might be more willing to help.